# Двойные сессии в wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, сессия, wordpress-плагины

Пишу плагин. В плагине на хук init вешаю функцию старта сессии.

- plugin.php

  ```
  add_action('init', 'startSession', 1);
  ```
- Функция 'startSession'

  ```
  function startSession()
  {
      session_start();

      $debugHandler = fopen(PLUGIN_PATH . 'debug.txt', 'a+');
      fwrite($debugHandler, current_time('mysql') . ' - ' . session_id() . "\n");
      fclose($debugHandler);
  }
  ```

Проблема возникает иногда. Заключается в том, что за одну загрузку страницы генерируются 2 сессии: одна из которых текущая (с момента открытия браузера), вторая - не понимаю откуда берётся.
Отслеживаю при помощи записи лога в файл debug.txt - последние 3 строчки в функции.

Задача: Избавиться от лишней сессии легальным способом...

Новая информация:

Для второй сессии $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] = 'WordPress/4.9.8;http://site.loc'. Для первой сессии там лежит информация о браузере.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В результате тестирования выяснилось, что вторая сессия создаётся не браузером пользователя, а движком Wordpress. Определил это по переменной $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], которая содержала строку 'WordPress/4.9.8;...'.

Решил задачу тем, что перед запуском сессии проверяю $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] на наличие в ней подстроки 'Wordpress'. Если подстроки не найдено, то сессию стартую.

Answer (score 0):

У вас за время одной загрузки страницы может несколько раз срабатывать ваша функция из-за того, что на странице выполняются ajax-запросы из js.

Используйте функцию `session_status()` для проверки текущего состояния сессии.

Comment: Но ведь даже если есть какой-то ajax-запрос, то запуская мою функцию он так же стартует сессию. По определению функция session_start() должна возобновить существующую сессию. Т.е. вроде как дополнительной сессии не должно быть...

Comment: @iziit а что, ваш код выводит разные session_id?

Comment: Да, именно так. Первая всегда текущая, которая создалась при первом запуске браузера.

Comment: @iziit выведите имя этой сессии и ищите по коду, где она создаётся

Comment: Не совсем понимаю о каком имени идёт речь...

Comment: В wordpress по умолчанию сессия не стартуется. Сторонних плагинов и тем мной не используется. Т.е. где стартуется сессия известно. Может это особенность wordpress или openserver или браузера?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.session-name.php